# android app uses more RAM than max heap size on some phones

Tags: android, memory, size, heap-memory, sony

I have an app that runs OK on most phones(such as Nexus **): the memory usage never goes above 24MB.
But on my Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc, after running for a few days, it uses more than 70MB RAM (according to Settings->Application->Running services).

Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() says my phone has a max heap size of only 32MB.

Is there any way to find out what's going on with my app on this phone?

Here's the adb meminfo for this app:

```
C:\>adb -d shell dumpsys meminfo 4606
Applications Memory Usage (kB):
Uptime: 409334045 Realtime: 585217200

** MEMINFO in pid 4606 [com.*****************] **
                    native   dalvik    other    total
            size:    60796    10695      N/A    71491
       allocated:    54057     6091      N/A    60148
            free:     6706     4604      N/A    11310
           (Pss):    56549     1129     8385    66063
  (shared dirty):     2128     1304     4964     8396
    (priv dirty):    56496      892     8156    65544

 Objects
           Views:        0        ViewRoots:        0
     AppContexts:        0       Activities:        0
          Assets:        3    AssetManagers:        3
   Local Binders:        5    Proxy Binders:       14
Death Recipients:      222
 OpenSSL Sockets:        2

 SQL
               heap:      425         MEMORY_USED:      425
 PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW:       81         MALLOC_SIZE:       50

 DATABASES
      pgsz     dbsz   Lookaside(b)  Dbname
         1       54            223  *.db
         1       27            198  **.db
         1        5             24  ***.db
         1       11             56  ****.db

C:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

The memory usage of native code is not restricted by the Java heap size, so applications can easily exceed that limit.  While this does mean Android is more likely to kill your application when it is in the background, it shouldn't be a problem as long as you don't exceed the available RAM on the device.

If you are seeing different memory use over time on one phone but not the other (and both apps are being interacted with in the same manner) then I would guess that the manufacturer's custom build of Android on that particular phone has a memory leak that you are triggering.  If that is the case, then there isn't much you can do about it.  It wouldn't hurt to look through your own code just to make sure the memory leak isn't your fault, however.

That being said, 70MB isn't anything to worry about on modern devices.  You should be safe on most phones as as you stick under ~150MB.

Comment: Half a day later it reached 85MB, and next time I checked, it was killed by the system (RAM usage went down to 20MB and PID was changed).

Comment: I do get a comment on market says this app goes above 150MB on his phone.